# BeautifulSoup sometimes gives exceptions

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, web-crawler

The strange thing is that sometimes the BeautifulSoup object does give the desired data, but other times I get an error like or `listindex error` or `out of range` or `nonetype object does not have attribute findNext()`, which is data that is nested inside other elements.

This is the code :

```
url = 'http://www.computerstore.nl/product/470130/category-208983/asrock-z97-extreme6.html'
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)

a = soup.find(text=('Socket')).find_next('dd').string

print(a)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem is that the cell value is not always `Socket`, **sometimes** it is *surrounded with tabs or spaces*. Instead of checking for the exact `text` match, pass a [compiled regular expression pattern](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression):

```
import re

soup.find(text=re.compile('Socket')).find_next('dd').get_text(strip=True)
```

Always prints `1150`.

---

Explaining that "sometimes" word I've used (thanks to @carpetsmoker for the initial proposal in comments):

if you open up the page, then, clean up the cookies and refresh the page, you may see two different looks of the same page:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the blocks on the page are arranged differently. Hence, the same page has two different looks and the HTML source - what you see is an [AB-testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) technique:

> In marketing and business intelligence, A/B testing is jargon for a
>   randomized experiment with two variants, A and B, which are the
>   control and treatment in the controlled experiment. It is a form of
>   statistical hypothesis testing with two variants leading to the
>   technical term, Two-sample hypothesis testing, used in the field of
>   statistics.

In other words, they are experimenting with the product page and gathering stats, like click-rate, number of sales made etc.

---

FYI, Here's the working code I've got at the moment:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

session = requests.Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36'}
session.get('http://www.computerstore.nl', headers=headers)

response = session.get('http://www.computerstore.nl/product/470130/category-208983/asrock-z97-extreme6.html', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
print(soup.find(text=re.compile('Socket')).find_next('dd').get_text(strip=True))
```

Comment: "*anti web-scraping technique*"; No, this seems to be AB-testing; if you disable cookies in your browser, and open a few tabs, you will get a different HTML page in some :-)

Comment: I tried to maintain the same page layout by echoing the cookies back, but there doesn't seem to be an obvious way of getting which page you're actually looking at, so you're stuck with the same problem, but that's just ugly :-/

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I've updated the answer - it is clearly AB-testing. Thanks again for the hint.

Comment: Ok you are right about the socket it works now thanks for that but i have this issue also for two other data 'Formaat Moederbord' and 'Chipset' . If i use the code you said and put instead of 'Socket' 'Formaat Moederbord' or 'Chipset' it does the problem again  how can i solve this.

Comment: @user3660293 well, it is working for the `Chipset` in the same way it was working for the `Socket`, but `Formaat Moederbord` - it is a different story, here is how you can find it (works in both A and B cases) `print(soup.find(text=re.compile('Formaat moederbord')).find_parent(['td', 'dt']).find_next(['td', 'dd']).find_next(['td', 'dd']).get_text(strip=True))`.

Comment: @user3660293 Are you trying to get the specs of the products? I think you'll be better off using icecat.biz; I think that is where coolblue gets it's info from, anyway. So the data will be exactly the same...

Comment: a = soup.find(text=re.compile('Formaat moederbord')).find_parent(['td', 'dt']).find_next(['td', 'dd']).find_next(['td', 'dd']).get_text(strip=True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_parent'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: This error do i get if i try the code for Formaat moederbord

Comment: And the above code also doesn't work for Chipset. the only thing working now is the Socket. but i do want to grab also the Formaat moederbord and the Chipset .

Comment: O it does work, i switched it to another url accidently.The code above does work so now i  do get them all from each item awesome thanks man

Answer (score -1):

This means that the data returned by the store doesn't contain the elements you seek for some reason.

Add some proper error handling to the code which catches the exceptions and dumps the input when it breaks. That way, you can see what was downloaded and improve the code.

A first step would be:

```
try:
    a = soup.find(text=('Socket')).find_next('dd').string

    print(a)
except:
    print(plain_text)
    raise
```

If it's a lot of text, then write it to a file.

It's also dangerous to string so many operations in a single line. If something goes wrong, then you won't know what. Split this into several lines, so you can quickly see whether it could find `Socket` or the `dd` element, etc.

Comment: *"You should improve your error handling"* seems more appropriate for a comment than an answer to me ...

Answer (score -1):

I made a suggested change to your code:

```
url = 'http://www.computerstore.nl/product/470130/category-208983/asrock-z97-extreme6.html'
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)

if soup.find(text=('Socket')):
   a = soup.find(text=('Socket')).find_next('dd').string
else:
   # Display some error info, and/or do some error logging
   print "error"

print(a)
```

Comment: You should only post full answers, and not comments on how to improve the code. Those could be left as comments on the question or pehaps na Answer...

Comment: So, help me improve my understanding.  In the context of alexce's original question, how could or would my answer become a "full" answer?

Comment: See [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer); it's a bit different from most forums and such, where it's fine to just give useful hints such as this. The great advantage of this, is that it greatly reduces the amount of "noise" when you end up at a page like this through an internet search or somesuch (on forums, you sometimes have pages and pages of junk to dig through) ...

Comment: Thanks for the help page link.  But, I didn't see anything that mentioned anything about "full" answers and I'm still confused about what made my answer non-full?  Especially, considering I used the person's original question supplemented by my solution.